# Componente Select com uma requisição Angular

Tags: angularjs, html5, html-select

Tenho um componente select

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option data-tokens="distrito">Distrito</option>
        <option data-tokens="bairro">Bairro</option>
        <option data-tokens="municipio">Município</option>
</select>
```

e, em cada `<option>` quero colocar uma requisição do Angular que esta em um `href`

```
<a href="/municipios">Busca Municípios</a>
```

Comment: está meio confusa sua pergunta, no `click` do `option` vc quer dizer? a link da requisição que está em um `href`?

Comment: sim, o link da requisição está em um `href` e quero por em um componente `select` que ao ser selecionado chama aquela requisição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de fazer o que desejas, a primeira é invocar o click no `change`, dessa forma:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('selectpicker')[0].addEventListener('change', handleEvent);

function handleEvent() {
  console.log(this.value);
  switch (this.value) {
    case 'Município':
      document.getElementById('municipio').click();
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
            <option data-tokens="distrito">Distrito</option>
            <option data-tokens="bairro">Bairro</option>
            <option data-tokens="municipio">Município</option>
</select>

<a id="municipio" href="/municipios">Busca Municípios</a>
```

Uma segunda opção é controlar no Angular. Exemplo:

```js
angular.module('select', []).controller('ctrl', function($http, $scope) {

  $scope.handleEvent = function() {
    console.log($scope.opcao);
    switch($scope.opcao) {
      case 'Município':
        // efetuar uma requisicao http
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="select" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" ng-model="opcao" ng-change="handleEvent()">
        <option data-tokens="distrito">Distrito</option>
        <option data-tokens="bairro">Bairro</option>
        <option data-tokens="municipio">Município</option>
</select>

  <a href="/municipios">Busca Municípios</a>
</div>
```